# Separate/Split single field in to multiple fields

Tags: sql-server

I have a table 'Waterwatch_Active' that has a field 'Att'.

The Att field is a complex concatenated field (it looks like html actually) that I need to split out in to:

- site_name
- site_code

This is an example of the Att field of my table Waterwatch_Active [Waterwatch_active example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPlbC.png)

```
textattributes>\n  <li><strong><span class="atr-name">site_name</span>:</strong> <span class="atr-value">Walkers Lake</span></li>\n  <li><strong><span class="atr-name">site_code</span>:</strong> <span class="atr-value">NC_LWA001</span></li>\n  \n  \n  <li><strong><span class="atr-name">basin_name</span>:</strong> <span class="atr-value">Avoca River</span></li>\n  \n  \n  \n  <li><strong><span class="atr-name">water_type</span>:</strong> <span class="atr-value">Other</span></li>\n  <li><strong><span class="atr-name">lng</span>:</strong> <span class="atr-value">142.923793</span></li>\n  <li><strong><span class="atr-name">lat</span>:</strong> <span class="atr-value">-36.540724</span></li>\n  <li><strong><span class="atr-name">zone</span>:</strong> <span class="atr-value">54</span></li>\n  \n  \n  <li><strong><span class="atr-name">public_url</span>:</strong> <span class="atr-value">http://www.vic.waterwatch.org.au/site/170005</span></li>\n</ul>

textattributes>\n  <li><strong><span class="atr-name">site_name</span>:</strong> <span class="atr-value">Murray River behind Koondrook PS</span></li>\n  <li><strong><span class="atr-name">site_code</span>:</strong> <span class="atr-value">NC_MUR400</span></li>\n  \n  \n  <li><strong><span class="atr-name">basin_name</span>:</strong> <span class="atr-value">Loddon River</span></li>\n  <li><strong><span class="atr-name">catchment_name</span>:</strong> <span class="atr-value">Loddon River</span></li>\n  <li><strong><span class="atr-name">sub_catchment_name</span>:</strong> <span class="atr-value">Loddon River</span></li>\n  <li><strong><span class="atr-name">reach_name</span>:</strong> <span class="atr-value">7_38 Gunbower Creek</span></li>\n  <li><strong><span class="atr-name">water_type</span>:</strong> <span class="atr-value">Other</span></li>\n  <li><strong><span class="atr-name">lng</span>:</strong> <span class="atr-value">144.130368</span></li>\n  <li><strong><span class="atr-name">lat</span>:</strong> <span class="atr-value">-35.633233</span></li>\n  <li><strong><span class="atr-name">zone</span>:</strong> <span class="atr-value">55</span></li>\n  \n  \n  <li><strong><span class="atr-name">public_url</span>:</strong> <span class="atr-value">http://www.vic.waterwatch.org.au/site/170021</span></li>\n</ul>
```

I have figured out how to pick out one at a time but I need it to all happen at once and produce a single resulting table. This is how I've managed to get site_name out:

```
--site_name
DECLARE @SiteNamekeysValueToSearch NVARCHAR(4000) = '"atr-value">'
DECLARE @SiteNameuntilThisCharAppears NVARCHAR(4000) = '</span>'
DECLARE @SiteNamekeysValueToSearchPattern NVARCHAR(4000) = '%' + @SiteNamekeysValueToSearch + '%'

SELECT SUBSTRING(
           Att,
           PATINDEX(@SiteNamekeysValueToSearchPattern, Att) + LEN(@SiteNamekeysValueToSearch),
           CHARINDEX(
               @SiteNameuntilThisCharAppears,
               Att,
               PATINDEX(@SiteNamekeysValueToSearchPattern, Att) + LEN(@SiteNamekeysValueToSearch)
           ) -(PATINDEX(@SiteNamekeysValueToSearchPattern, Att) + LEN(@SiteNamekeysValueToSearch))
       )
FROM Waterwatch_Active
--End site_name
```

So ideally I'd like my resulting table to look like this
[Waterwatch_Active result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ov7sV.png)

```
+----------------------------------+-----------+
|            Site_Name             | Site_Code |
+----------------------------------+-----------+
| Walkers Lake                     | NC_LWA001 |
| Murray River behind Koondrook PS | NC_MUR400 |
+----------------------------------+-----------+
```

Please any help will be greatly appreciated, I'm in over my head but I'm determined not to give up.

Comment: You might want to consider using an HTML/XML parser to handle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are processing this row by row, then you can use the following to get the site_name. You can modify it to get other attributes.

The code converts the string into a valid xml string (it needs a `<ul>` at the front, then uses an xpath query to get the value of the site_name:

Substituent *your string* for your (almost) xml string.

```
declare @xml xml
set @xml=convert(xml,'<ul>'+'*your string*')
select @xml.value('(/ul/li/strong/span[text()="site_name"]/../../span)[1]','varchar(100)')
```

If you want to do this against a table:

```
select convert(xml,'<ul>'+att).value('(/ul/li/strong/span[text()="site_name"]/../../span)[1]','varchar(100)') as SiteName
from waterwatch_active
```

lastly, if you are doing multiple columns, such as site_name and site_code, do this:

```
;with attTable as (select convert(xml,'<ul>'+att) as attXML from waterwatch_active)
select attXML.value('(/ul/li/strong/span[text()="site_name"]/../../span)[1]','varchar(100)') as SiteName,
attXML.value('(/ul/li/strong/span[text()="site_code"]/../../span)[1]','varchar(100)') as SiteCode
from attTable
```

Comment: Hi Tom, Thanks for your reply. The first example works great. I've tried the 2nd and 3rd examples and I get an error message "The data types varchar and text are incompatible in the add operator." What am I missing?

Comment: I suspect that the column type in the table is text. You will need to convert that to varchar(4000), hopefully that is long enough. So the first CTE would be `convert(xml,'<ul>'+convert(varchar(4000),att))`